# What can I do if my Olympus E520 is randomly turning off and on in certain camera positions?

Tags: troubleshooting, olympus

I've owned an Olympus E520 for around 3 1/2 years. Last year it started behaving erratically - whenever I turn it on it randomly turns off and on for a while, mostly on certain camera positions. I don't know if it's the selection wheel or the on/off switch. <strike>Any comments as to why this might be happening, and</strike> any suggestions on fixing it?

*UPDATE*:

Being able to go home for the holidays allowed me to pick up my camera, after a detailed observation and testing the camera I found a false contact in the on/off switch basically I need to be pushing the switch in the ON position for the camera to stay on. Now I have figured out the first part of my question, but second half remains.

Comment: How old is the battery?

Comment: same as camera, but I have a newer one and it does the same thing @inkista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cameras are usually quite tricky beasts to service for yourself, that's if you can even get a replacement part.  The manufacturer will have a service department, though given the age you'd probably be better off looking at an independent repairer.

Camera shops, especially independent ones, can either take care of it or give you the contact information for somebody reputable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're feeling intrepid, here's [a youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nbT_uQEG9A0) of someone completely unafraid of tracking dozens of tiny screws, cleaning the on/off switch contacts on his E520.  It looks as if to gain access to the contacts, you have to remove both the back and top plates (and accessing some of the screws for the top plate require peeling back the rubber on the grip).

Whether it's a dirty or broken contact/spring or something else that's your issue, you can't tell, so this may or may not work, obviously [voids any warranty](https://www.thinkgeek.com/product/8f52/) ;), and could damage the camera further, so most folks would probably go for manufacturer service. But if the camera's worthless to you as-is, and you like messing about with electronics (this is SE, after all), what the hey, might be worth a shot.